# Django Match Model Choice Field to Foreignkey

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-filter

I'm trying to make a Quiz App for my College...
I want to map every department to a Faculty

> models.py

```py
Class Faculty(models.Model):
    faculty_choice = [
        ("FOE","faculty of engineering"),
        ("FOS","faculty of science"),
        ("FOA","faculty of Agriculture"),
    ]

    faculty = models.CharField(
        max_length=3,
        choices=faculty_choice,
        default=FOE,
    )

Class Department(models.Model):
    Faculty = models.FOREIGNKEY( Faculty, on_delete=CASCADE)
    #this is where my problem is I don't know the next step
```

Under the Faculty of engineering we have other options to

Like

### Faculty Of Engineering

1. Mechanical
2. Electrical
3. Civil

### Faculty Of Science

1. Mathematics
2. Physics
3. Chemistry

### Faculty Of Agriculture

1. Animal
2. Plants
3. Economy and extension

*hope my question is descriptive enough❓*

Answer (score 0):

You are doing everything correct, just create `department_name` in your `Department` model:

```
faculty_choice = [
        ("FOE", "faculty of engineering"),
        ("FOS", "faculty of science"),
        ("FOA", "faculty of Agriculture"),
    ]


class Faculty(models.Model):
    faculty_name = models.CharField(choices=faculty_choice, default='FOE')


class Department(models.Model):
    department_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    faculty = models.ForeignKey(Faculty, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='departments')
```

Then you can access department fields using `related_name` from `Faculty` class object. Assuming `foe` is Faculty object, using:

```
foe.departments.all()
```

will give you all instances of `Department` model that have relation with `foe`